# CodeIgniter 4: Define/include "globally available" arrays and functions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'd like to define some arrays and functions that I can access "globally" in all controllers/models/views (in codeigniter 4).
For example I need to define an array of available currencies:

```
$currencies = array("EUR","USD");
```

And some functions e.g. to display numbers differently depending on the users country as some use decimal points or commas.

Where would I put those arrays and functions and how would I include them so they are available within all controllers/models/views?

I researched that you can define constants in app/config/Constants.php but it doesn't seem to be the place for arrays and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to separate fact from opinion here.

> ...define some arrays and functions that I can access "globally" in
> all controllers/models/views...

1. Use inheritance - You can create 'base' classes that your Controllers and Models extend from; these 'base' classes extend *CodeIgniter's* Controller or Model, and define any methods you want within all of *your* Controllers or Models.

   Each Controller or Model you create that extends its respective 'base' class will have access to anything (non-private) that you define in the 'base' class.
2. Use namespacing- In truth, that's the power of it. If you really need something you can access from "anywhere", create a Library or something similar. It really doesn't matter what it is as long as it's within a defined namespace.

   Then when you need to use this Library (or whatever), you create an instance and use it. You could even use static members if you didn't want to actually create an object.
3. Use 'Helpers'- To stay procedural you can both [extend the functionality of existing CI4 Helpers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers) or even [create your own](https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/custom-helper-in-codeigniter-4/#Create_Custom_Helper). You can find other resources on this as well.

> ...you can define constants in app/config/Constants.php but it doesn't
> seem to be the place for arrays and functions.

Defining array constants inside `Constants.php` is fine so long as you're actually defining a constant; `$currencies = array("EUR","USD");` is not a constant.

You're correct about functions in that file, however; you should not do that.

---

A quick smattering of opinion based on general(ish) consensus:

The purpose of Controllers is to properly route requests; the purpose of Views (broadly speaking) is to render web pages. Neither of these is truly the place to be performing any business logic; hence the catchphrase "fat models, skinny controllers".

If you think you need to access or perform business logic outside of the Models, stop for a second and ask yourself why that isn't occurring in the Model layer instead.

Comment: Great explanation. I understand in general we should use classes in CI4, but what about the file app/Common.php, normal functions in there work just fine. Any disadvantage?

Comment: @TomSenner There could be... Like the file comment mentions, "the goal of this file is to allow developers a location where they can overwrite core procedural functions and replace them with their own" so you will have to be careful that your naming scheme doesn't conflict with any existing functions. This is another benefit of namespacing: you don't have to worry about repeating method names so long as they're not in the exact same namespace.

Comment: @TomSenner Added a little more on Helpers, as that is another option you might find useful.